# How I do to make the Notebook use all space below 'Flota'?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

The notebook does not expand and it looks so small.

I have tried with grid geometry and pack(fill='both', expand='yes'), that didn't worked. I know my code is in spanish but i think it is understandable for english speakers.

I also tried to create a frame below 'Flota' tittle and make the notebook pack there but it dosen't work.

The foto i have attached is how it looks now with the code I'm sharing.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


# screen and root settings
# crear ventana
root = tk.Tk()

# info de la pantalla
width= root.winfo_screenwidth()
height= root.winfo_screenheight()

# tamaño de la ventana
"""root.geometry("%dx%d" % (width, height))"""
root.title("Gestor de Flotas - Tallers Citoler")
root.geometry("1600x900")

# ventana en mitad de pantalla
pwidth = round(width/2-1600/2)
pheight = round(height/2-900/2)
root.geometry(str(1600)+"x"+str(900)+"+"+str(pwidth)+"+"+str(pheight))

# no cambiar tamaño ventana
root.resizable(False, False)

# titulo de ventana
root.title("Tallers Citoler - Gestor de flotas")

# color de fondo de la ventana, de momento no pongo ninguno
root.config(bg='blue')
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)



###############################################################
# TOP SIDE
# etiqueta titulo (tittle label)
frame_titulo = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief=tk.FLAT,bg='black')
frame_titulo.grid(sticky='N', columnspan=2)

etiqueta_titulo = tk.Label(frame_titulo, text='Tallers Citoler - Sistema de Gestion de Flotas', fg='black', font=('Dosis', 48), bg= 'darksalmon', padx=147, pady=1)
etiqueta_titulo.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='N')   



###############################################################
# LEFT SIDE
# left frame
panel_izquierdo = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief=tk.FLAT, bg='black')
panel_izquierdo.grid(row=1, column=0)

fondo_izquierdo = tk.Label(panel_izquierdo, padx=270, pady=401, bg='white')
fondo_izquierdo.grid()

# 'flota' label
frame_cartel_flota = tk.Frame(panel_izquierdo, bd=1, relief=tk.FLAT, bg='black')
frame_cartel_flota.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='N')

cartel_flota = tk.Label(frame_cartel_flota, text='Flota', font=('Dosis', 34), bg= '#EED5B7', padx=220)
cartel_flota.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='N')

# panel botones y flota (grey panel below 'Flota' tittle)
frame_botones_flota = tk.Frame(panel_izquierdo, bd=1, relief=tk.FLAT, bg='black')
frame_botones_flota.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='S')

"""cartel_botones_flota = tk.Label(frame_botones_flota, bg= 'lightgrey', padx=270, pady=371)
cartel_botones_flota.grid(row=0,column=0)"""

# Notebook
# Crear pestañas flota
notebook_flota = ttk.Notebook(frame_botones_flota)
notebook_flota.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='N')

p1 = ttk.Frame(notebook_flota)
p2 = ttk.Frame(notebook_flota)
p3 = ttk.Frame(notebook_flota)

# agregar pestañas
notebook_flota.add(p1, text='Carretillas')
notebook_flota.add(p2, text='Elevadores')
notebook_flota.add(p3, text='Vehiculos')



###############################################################
# RIGHT SIDE
# right frame
panel_derecho = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief=tk.FLAT, bg='black')
panel_derecho.grid(row=1, column=1)

fondo_derecho = tk.Label(panel_derecho, padx=525, pady=401, bg='red')
fondo_derecho.grid()

# 'recordatorios' label
frame_cartel_recordatorios = tk.Frame(panel_derecho, bd=1, relief=tk.FLAT, bg='black')
frame_cartel_recordatorios.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='N')

cartel_recordatorios = tk.Label(frame_cartel_recordatorios, text='Recordatorios', font=('Dosis', 34), bg= 'khaki', padx=384)
cartel_recordatorios.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='N')

#panel info recordatorios (big yellow label)
frame_info_recordatorios = tk.Frame(panel_derecho, bd=1, relief=tk.FLAT, bg='black')
frame_info_recordatorios.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='S')

cartel_info_recordatorios = tk.Label(frame_info_recordatorios, bg= 'yellow', padx=525, pady=371)
cartel_info_recordatorios.grid(row=0,column=0)



###############################################################
# ejecucion de la ventana
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is better not to put two frames in same grid row and use `sticky='N'` and `stick='S'` to show them.  Put the two frames in different grid rows instead.

Comment: HI! thanks for your answer, i solved this using packing it to the root and taking away the panel in where I was placeing it, so now it looks cool. Any ways thanks for asking and i note your tip for future works!